# How to add the "series" attribute for a "book" entry in Mendeley

Tags: mendeley

I see in the [API Reference](https://dev.mendeley.com/methods/#additional-document-attributes) there is a `series` attribute, but this field is not exposed when editing a "Book" type entry either in the Windows Desktop app or online.

**UPDATE**: When I use their [API Explorer](https://api.mendeley.com/apidocs/docs) to add the attribute in JSON format for an existing book using their Update document API, I can see the `series` attribute added, both in the Desktop app and online!  That verifies the attribute is applicable to a book entry type.

But the question remains: How do I make the `series` attribute appear when editing / adding a "book" entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to make additional attributes appear for a particular document type.  In the Desktop app, you can go to Tools -> Options.  Under the Document Details tab, you select the document type, then check the attributes you want to be shown by default.

However, I cannot find a similar method for the web application version.